# Deleting lines. My algorithm for solving the problem does not work

Tags: c#

I need to decide to complete the solution so that all text is removed after any comment markers. Any spaces at the end of the line must be removed
My code:

```
public static string StripComments(string text, string[] commentSymbols)
{
    string[] str = text.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        int index=0;
        if (str[i].IndexOf(commentSymbols[0]) != -1)
        {
            index = str[i].IndexOf(commentSymbols[0], StringComparison.Ordinal)-1;
            str[i] = str[i].Remove(index)+"\n";
        }
        else if (str[i].IndexOf(commentSymbols[1]) != -1)
        {
            index = str[i].IndexOf(commentSymbols[1],StringComparison.Ordinal)-1;
            str[i] = str[i].Remove(index)+"\n";
        }
        else {
          str[i]+="\n";
        }
    }
    str[str.Length-1]=str[str.Length-1].Remove(str[str.Length-1].LastIndexOf('\n'));
    return string.Join("",str).TrimEnd();
}
```

For example:

```
string stripped = StripCommentsSolution.StripComments("apples, pears # and bananas\ngrapes\nbananas !apples", new [] { "#", "!" })
```

// result should == "apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas"

When running tests, it throws an error:

> Expected string length 6 but was 8. Strings differ at index 1.
> Expected: "a \ n b \ nc"    But was: "a \ n b \ nc"

Comment: Can you show the failing test?

Comment: When removing you have to start at end of list.  If you have 4,5,6  and remove 4 then the items above 4 drop one index number.  So use : for (int i = str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: BTW: you code would be simpler if you did not add all those "\n" in the loop but instead do a `string.Join("\n",str)` at the end

Comment: @jdweng I don't think this is relevant as nothing gets removed from the array `str`.

Comment: What's with regex? You need regex which start with commentsign and ends with whitespace. Then you have it

Comment: @ Klaus Gütter : You do not understand the issue.  When you remove an item in the middle the length changes so you get an index exception.  Starting at the end of the string you will not get an index exception.

Comment: @jdweng but nothing is removed from the array `str`, only the array elements are modified (but each is touched only once)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each of the `commentSymbols` is exactly 1 character long as in your example? If yes, why is it not `char[] commentSymbols`?

Comment: @evgeny20 This is solved now, i have tested my second solution with your link to codewars. So it can be closed. You should accept an answer for fairness

Comment: @RoXTar I accepted you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause of @evgeny20 mentioned in comments, he want's it without regexes here one solution i found, without it.

```
public static string StripComments(string text, string[] commentSymbols)
{
       string[] lines = text.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
       lines = lines.Select(x => x.Split(commentSymbols, StringSplitOptions.None).First().TrimEnd()).ToArray();
       return string.Join("\n", lines);
}
```

Best Regards and happy learning

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Solution, have a try

you need this using...
`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
public static string StripComments(string text, string[] commentSymbols)
{            
    foreach (string commentSymbol in commentSymbols)
    {
          text = Regex.Replace(text, $"{commentSymbol}[^\\n]*", "");
    }
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "\\s*(\\n+)", "$1");
    return text;
}
```

**Edit:**
Regex changed that line ends are trimmed too

Best Regards

Comment: You will receive a message: "apples, pears grapes\nbananas ". It won't work

Comment: sorry. Have changed it, it is now as requestet "apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas"

Comment: Expected: "apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas"
  But was:  "apples, pears \ngrapes\nbananas "
You do not fully understand the meaning of working with Regex

Comment: you will remove the space too?

Comment: @Evgeny20 i have changed it so that the end of lines are trimmed too, for me it appears "apples, pears\ngrapes\nbananas" now

Comment: you said i don't understand regex, but i think you meant i don't really understand your requirement. Sorry

Comment: What will you do if this happens?
   Expected: "a \ nc \ nd"
   But was: "a \ nc \ nd $ e f g"
   ------------------ ^
The algorithm does not work correctly for all lines
For example you have:
"apples, pears # and bananas
grapes
bananas !apples"
You need to recieve:
"apples, pears
grapes
bananas"
And in general, your solution would work correctly, your Regex pattern is not intended for all cases.

Comment: Or Expected: "\n\nDEA\n\nE\n\nFEA\n\nC\n\nE\n\n\n\nAD\n\nAE\n\nD\n\n\n\nC\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nF\n\n\n\nE\n\n\n\nBAB\n..."
  But was:  "DEA\nE\nFEA\nC\nE\nAD\nAE\nD\nC\nF\nE\nBAB\nF\nB\nCD\nA\nB\nF\nACCD\nA\nEE\nF\nE\nEF..."

Comment: but i thing regex is your solution and for other cases as you requestet you must change it.

Comment: what is your Input for this : "\n\nDEA\n\nE\n\nFEA\n\nC\n\nE\n\n\n\nAD\n\nAE\n\nD\n\n\n\nC\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nF\n\n\n\nE\n\n\n\nBAB\n..."

Comment: your task as you have set it is solved. You now have further requirements, then you should make them concrete

Comment: Described here in detail
[link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51c8e37cee245da6b40000bd)

Comment: this is only what you have written here and the solution is above. Provide other samples

Comment: but in the end, even your code with 5,000 if-else cannot be your claim. In any case you should use regex. But you will only find the right one with the correct requirement.

Comment: This assumes that none of the cmment symbols contain a character that is used as regex meta-character (e.g. a '.').

Comment: @Klaus Gütter - but the commentsign can be escaped before

Comment: @Evgeny20 my second solution above has passed the test.

Comment: I don't really like regular expressions in terms of the bulkiness of regex patterns)

Comment: @RoXTar My weak theme

Answer (score 0):

In general, your code seems a resonable approach. It does however not cover:

- more or less than two commentSymbols
- lines containing more than one comment symbol

The following code handles these cases:

```
public static string StripComments(string text, string[] commentSymbols)
{
    string[] str = text.Split('\n');
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        int index = -1;
        // find first occurrence of any commentSymbol in str[i]
        foreach (var commentSymbol in commentSymbols)
        {
            int indexOfThisSymbol = str[i].IndexOf(commentSymbol);
            if (indexOfThisSymbol != -1 && (index == -1 || indexOfThisSymbol < index))
                index = indexOfThisSymbol;
        }
        if (index != -1)
        {
            // strip off comment symbol and everything after it
            str[i] = str[i].Substring(0, index);
        }
        // strip off trailing spaces
        str[i] = str[i].TrimEnd();
    }
    // combine again
    return string.Join("\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i can provide a second Solution like i understand your  request.
Please have a look.

```
public static string StripComments(string text, string[] commentSymbols)
{
     var textLines = text.Split("\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < textLines.Length;i++ )
     {
          foreach (string commentSymbol in commentSymbols)
          {
               textLines[i] = Regex.Replace(textLines[i], $"{Regex.Escape(commentSymbol)}[^\\n]*", "");
          }
          textLines[i] = textLines[i].TrimEnd();
     }            
     return string.Join("\n",textLines);
}
```

this preserves all line breaks and removes comments and whitespaces as requested in your link.
If it isn't right, you can give a more constructive example. At least I'm trying to help you.

**EDIT:** this solution now supports Regex Specialcharacters as commentsymbol

`With this i passed the test in codewars successfully`

Best Regards

Comment: You could add Regex.Escape(commentSymbol) to make this solution also cover symbols which  are special regex chars